# android studio cannot resolve Symbol R after importing a gradle project as module

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, import

after importing a gradle project that has **apply plugin: 'com.android.library'** into another gradle project and add it as dependency so i could use an activity and its classes, it throws an exception **cannot resolve Symbol R**

it seems all solution comming from last year are outdated and cannot be seen on the latest android studio **(version 2.2.2)**

Comment: Just Click on Build -> Rebuild Project option in your Android Studio.

Comment: tried and still not fix

Answer (score 1):

You can try this,
Build => Clean Project 
then you will get the error, error might be change in layout.xml file or string.xml file... solve it

Comment: after build => clean error still there, when the android library project is opened in another android studio and run on android device there was no error, only when that android library project is being import as gradle project in another android project when the error shown, I just wan to import and android project as a library in another project with out making it as .jar

Comment: just want to do something similar to eclipse when importing an android project to another android project

Comment: found the error, i though android studio would follow the sdk api level supplied in manifest, but gradle build file also has its own sdk api level, so after changing it, everything works fine now